# Updating a Membership Form with Dropdowns in PHP

Tags: php, forms, select, dropdown

I'm learning PHP and I struggle to find solutions to my issue. I've created a page where membership data can be edited. All my 'type=text' fields display the current value of the member correctly. But the values selected on the 2 drop down fields (Language and Interest) do not display in the edit field. They do update though to MySql but the 'Select One...' option display when I want to edit the members 'Language' and 'Interest' fields.

What should I do so that the current value of the 2 drop downs that is stored in the db, displays on the ui when a member needs to get edited?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

                $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not Found');

                include('dbconnect.php');

                try{

                    $sql = "SELECT id, firstName, lastName, idNumber, mobileNumber, email, birthDate, languageType, interest FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 0,1";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    $firstName = $row['firstName'];
                    $lastName = $row['lastName'];
                    $idNumber = $row['idNumber'];
                    $mobileNumber = $row['mobileNumber'];
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    $birthDate = $row['birthDate'];
                    $languageType = $row['languageType'];
                    $interest = $row['interest'];

                }

                catch(PDOException $exception){
                    die('ERROR: '.$exception->getMessage());
                }

            ?>

            <?php

            $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');

            include 'dbconnect.php';

            if($_POST){

                try{

                    $sql = "UPDATE members SET 
                                            firstName=:firstName, 
                                            lastName=:lastName, 
                                            idNumber=:idNumber,
                                            mobileNumber=:mobileNumber,
                                            email=:email,
                                            birthDate=:birthDate,
                                            languageType=:languageType,
                                            interest=:interest
                                    WHERE   id=:id";

                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                    $firstName = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['firstName']));
                    $lastName = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['lastName']));
                    $idNumber = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['idNumber']));
                    $mobileNumber = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['mobileNumber']));
                    $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
                    $birthDate = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['birthDate']));
                    $languageType = $_POST['languageType'];
                    $interest = $_POST['interest'];

                    $stmt->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':idNumber', $idNumber);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':mobileNumber', $mobileNumber);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':birthDate', $birthDate);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':languageType', $languageType);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':interest', $interest);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Member was updated.</div>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to update member. Please try again.</div>";
                    }

                }

                catch(PDOException $exception){
                    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
                }
            }
            ?>
```

And here is the  html:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?id={$id}");?>" method="post">
                <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='firstName' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($firstName, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='lastName' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lastName, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID Number</td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='idNumber' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idNumber, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mobile Number</td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='mobileNumber' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($mobileNumber, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='email' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Birth Date</td>
                        <td><input type='date' name='birthDate' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($birthDate, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Language</td>
                        <td>

                            <select name='languageType' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $languageType;  ?>" />

                              <option>Select One...</option>
                              <option>Afrikaans</option>
                              <option>English</option>
                              <option>Zulu</option>
                              <option>Xhosa</option>
                              <option>Venda</option>
                              <option>French</option>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Interest</td>
                        <td>

                            <select name='interest' class='form-control' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($interest, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" />

                                  <option>Select One...</option>
                                  <option>Golf</option>
                                  <option>Rugby</option>
                                  <option>Tennis</option>
                                  <option>Cricket</option>
                                  <option>Swimming</option>
                                  <option>Hiking</option>
                                  <option>Surfing</option>
                                  <option>Movies</option>
                                  <option>Swords</option>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='submit' value='Save Changes' class='btn btn-primary' />
                            <a href='index.php' class='btn btn-danger'>Back to read members</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: the value must be on option not select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all wrong :

```
<select name='languageType' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $languageType;  ?>" />

                              <option>Select One...</option>
                              <option>Afrikaans</option>
                              <option>English</option>
                              <option>Zulu</option>
                              <option>Xhosa</option>
                              <option>Venda</option>
                              <option>French</option>


  <select name='interest' class='form-control' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($interest, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" />

                                  <option>Select One...</option>
                                  <option>Golf</option>
                                  <option>Rugby</option>
                                  <option>Tennis</option>
                                  <option>Cricket</option>
                                  <option>Swimming</option>
                                  <option>Hiking</option>
                                  <option>Surfing</option>
                                  <option>Movies</option>
                                  <option>Swords</option>
```

The Select does not have a value attribute, the value attribute belong to option.

this is how your select should look :

```
<select name='languageType' class='form-control' />
<option value="Afrikaans">Afrikaans</option>
... <!-- Other options just like I did the first one -->
</select>
```

if you want the value from the database to be selected then you will need to check if the option is not equal to the db value then select it with the `selected` attribute of option.

like :

```
<select name='languageType' class='form-control' />
    <option value="">Select One...</option>
    <option value="Afrikaans"<?php if($languageType == "Afrikaans"){echo "selected='selected'";?>>Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="English" <?php if($languageType == "English"){echo "selected='selected'";?>>English</option>
    <option value="Zulu" <?php if($languageType == "English"){echo "selected='selected'";?>>Zulu</option>
    <option value="Xhosa" <?php if($languageType == "Xhosa"){echo "selected='selected'";?>>Xhosa</option>
    <option value="Venda" <?php if($languageType == "Venda"){echo "selected='selected'";?>>Venda</option>
    <option value="French" <?php if($languageType == "French"){echo "selected='selected'";?>>French</option>
</select>
```

Then do your second dropdown following the above as a guide, also don't forget to close the select option `</select>`

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks Masivuye Cokile. Just a small error - Missing the closing } in the php statement in the <option> tag. Thanks again